# how to print data to the console and read it back in?

Tags: r

I have some data that I printed out to the console:

```
> head(mydata)

V1                  V2        V3
1 29228 2005-01-01 00:00:00 12345
2 29228 2005-01-01 00:10:00 23456
3 29228 2005-01-01 00:20:00 34567
4 29228 2005-01-01 00:30:00 45678
```

I want to share this data with a colleague.  It would be great if I could have the data in an r script with my code rather than having to share a separate data file.

Is it possible to read this data in to R from a string, e.g.

```
> df <- read("
   V1                  V2        V3
   1 29228 2005-01-01 00:00:00 12345
   2 29228 2005-01-01 00:10:00 23456
   3 29228 2005-01-01 00:20:00 34567
   4 29228 2005-01-01 00:30:00 45678
")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you what to share your data with another R user.  It is better to use the dput command.
 For example:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"V1                  V2        V3 V4
1 29228 2005-01-01 00:00:00 12345
2 29228 2005-01-01 00:10:00 23456
3 29228 2005-01-01 00:20:00 34567
4 29228 2005-01-01 00:30:00 45678", header = TRUE)

dput(df)

structure(list(V1 = c(29228L, 29228L, 29228L, 29228L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2005-01-01", class = "factor"), V3 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("00:00:00", 
"00:10:00", "00:20:00", "00:30:00"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(12345L, 
23456L, 34567L, 45678L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

This output will preserve the original structure and formatting of the dataframe and with a more condensed form.  To read the data back in is just a simple:

```
newdf<- structure(list(V1 = c(29228L, 29228L, 29228L, 29228L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2005-01-01", class = "factor"), V3 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("00:00:00", 
"00:10:00", "00:20:00", "00:30:00"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(12345L, 
23456L, 34567L, 45678L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

This is also the preferred method of providing examples here at stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you have 4 columns.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"V1                  V2        V3 V4
1 29228 2005-01-01 00:00:00 12345
2 29228 2005-01-01 00:10:00 23456
3 29228 2005-01-01 00:20:00 34567
4 29228 2005-01-01 00:30:00 45678", header = TRUE)
```

you could also do

```
df = head(mydata)
```